# Run script when database return a value

Tags: javascript, php

I have a dropdown that runs a script when the value is changed. But now I want to return the selected value from the database and run a script when the selected value is: `2`.

Here is my dropdown:

```
<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
  <select class="form-control select2" id="status" name="status" style="width: 100%;">
    <option <?php echo ($row["status"] == "1") ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?> value="1">One</option>
    <option <?php echo ($row["status"] == "2") ? 'selected="selected"' : '';?> value="2">Two</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The result of the output should deployed here:

```
<p id="output1"></p>
```

This is the script that is running onchange:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var dataEl = document.querySelector('#status'),
  outputEl = document.querySelector('#output1');

  dataEl.onchange = function() {
    if (dataEl.value === "1") {
      outputEl.innerHTML = ' ';
    } else if (dataEl.value === "2") {
      outputEl.innerHTML = '<div>(script)</div>';
    }
  };
</script>
```

I want to keep the script for onchange. But I also want to run this script when the returned value from the database = `2`. I tried different scripts like adding a `dataEl.onLoad` script, but also this didnt show the script for value `2`.

Does someone know how I can do this?

Comment: use `$( "select option:selected" ).val()` to get the selected value of the selectbox

Comment: Do I need to put this in the javascript?

Comment: See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/z1wyz62s/

Comment: I fixed it with your help. Here is the full script: https://jsfiddle.net/z1wyz62s/3/. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the selected value of select options you need to use `selectedIndex`.

```
var e = document.getElementById("status");
var sel = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Primary Example: https://jsfiddle.net/z1wyz62s/

Complete example by @John: https://jsfiddle.net/z1wyz62s/3/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just call it?

```
dataEl.onchange = function() {
  if (dataEl.value === "1") {
    outputEl.innerHTML = ' ';
  } else if (dataEl.value === "2") {
    var result = your_script();
    outputEl.innerHTML = '<div>'+result+'</div>';
  }
};
```